# Where to upload an Image so that the URL stays the same for Glide

Tags: java, android, database, image, android-glide

I'm using Glide for one picture in my app, sometimes I want to change this picture.
I don't have a own database or server so I wonder if there is any other solution to upload an image to the internet, change it and the URL stays the same.

If I try it for example with Google Drive then it is a new URL everytime I upload a new image.
Hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another fantastic idea, Why dont you use github instead? create a git repo and upload your picture there. You can change your picture any point of time, Only one thing to remember is to have same file name for the picture everytime you use them.

i usually do it, Find my link below which i use may a times

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vinayjayaram/JsonFake/master/me.jpg?_sm_au_=iVVH0Zv57N03TfQR

Comment: That sounds like the most simple idea :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) database, it is simple and compact.

Check the tutorial for more details.

Firebase provides many other features like Crashlytics, Performance analysis, Test labs, etc

:)